# Only decode new line to html

Tags: php, html, html-entities, decoding

My string-filter functions puts this string

```
<b>enter</b>
Testing & so. "Some quote here";
```

into the database like this

```
&amp;#60;b&amp;#62;enter&amp;#60;/b&amp;#62;&amp;#13;&amp;#10;Testing &amp;#38; so. \&amp;#34;Some quote here\&#34;;
```

I echo it like this:
stripslashes(htmlspecialchars_decode(...));

which gives me:

```
<b>enter</b> Testing & so. "Some quote here";
```

How can I echo this string WITH the new line, but without allowing it to decode all the other html entities?

I've tried html_entity_decode(), but this also makes enter bold...

Thanks!

Comment: only *decode* seems wrong word here

Comment: what for you encoder entities while putting into DB? you should only do that on display

Comment: That's some horrible handling of encodings and escapes. Please start here: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Comment: For the life of me, I can't see why you got to -2 for this question :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Preserve and display text exactly how it is typed and submitted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21045667/preserve-and-display-text-exactly-how-it-is-typed-and-submitted)

Comment: Why is it horrible? I use this to filter the string:    $input=filter_var($input, FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);

Comment: 1) You double escape everything. 2) Why `stripslashes`? You only ever need it for magic quotes, which should be off anyway. 3) Never escape anything for the wrong medium. In this case: Why double HTML encode text which goes into the database, which has nothing to do with HTML?

Comment: (edited my comment above, still horrible?) thanks for replies!

Comment: Yes. I would never want to see text like *"&amp;#60;b&amp;#62;enter&amp;#60;/b&a"* in my database (unless a user explicitly typed exactly that).

Comment: I see... so the right way to do it, is to put the text "as is" in the database, and when echo-ing, runing filter_var? Isn't their a possible security issue then (I use prepared statements)?

Comment: Yes, *escape* for the medium that you are outputting to, no sooner than you're outputting to it. There's no security issue if you do escape your data. It's actually safer to have `echo htmlspecialchars($text)` right in your templates, because you are *sure* it's HTML escaped. Just `echo $text` means you're relying on other code to do this before, which is insecure.

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
$text = nl2br($text);
```

It will transform newlines to br

Comment: This will not transform newlines to `<br>`. It will insert `<br>` before the new lines. Here's a good comment on the PHP documentation on how to replace the new lines for windows/unix/mac: http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php#73440